# How to get the index of the list active element when there are no ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

How can I select the index of the `.active` `<li>` element?

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="0">‹</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="3">›</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I tried, but it returns always `1`:

```
var pageNumber = $('.pagination .page-item.active:first').index();
```

Comment: @ADyson no, the index of the active `<li>` element. If the 10th element has `.active` class, then I need to get `9`.

Comment: var index = $('li.active').index();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said you want

> ...the index of the active `<li>` element. If the 10th element has .active class, then I need to get `9`...

jQuery's [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function gives you that:

```
var index = $("li.page-item.active").index();
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log($("li.page-item.active").index());
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="0">‹</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="3">›</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong selector , simply use :

```
$("ul.pagination li.active").index()
```

**Demo:**

```js
console.log($("ul.pagination li.active").index());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="0">‹</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="3">›</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean one of these?

```js
$act = $("li.active")
console.log(
  $("li").index($act), // or
  $act.index()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="0">‹</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="3">›</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

These examples are working for me, both return 2 for the active element.

```js
console.log($('.pagination > li.active').index());//gets the index of the element relative to it's parent

console.log($('.pagination > li.active > a').data('dt-idx'));//gets the data-dt-idx value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="0">‹</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item ">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
        <a tabindex="0" class="page-link" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#" data-dt-idx="3">›</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```